# rvm --default not setting 1.9.2 ubuntu 11.10 + can't install rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rvm

My RVM is 1.9.2

I'm trying to set up rails.  For some reason I can't.  Here's what the env reports:

```
kevin@V130:~$ rvm list

rvm rubies

   ruby-1.8.7-p352 [ x86_64 ]
=> ruby-1.9.2-p290 [ x86_64 ]

kevin@V130:~$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]
```

Shouldn't that be listing 1.9.2?  It's been set as the --default.

when I gem `install rails` I get

```
kevin@V130:~$ sudo gem install rails
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load -- mkmf (LoadError)
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from extconf.rb:1:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.6.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.6.3/ext/json/ext/parser/gem_make.out
kevin@V130:~$
```

Comment: Your RVM is 1.9.2, or your Ruby version is 1.9.2? If you are running RVM 1.9.2 you should do `rvm get head` to update to a more current version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a system install of ruby in `/usr/bin` that takes precedence over the rvm versions. Make sure something like `~/.rvm/rubies/your-ruby-version/bin` is in your `PATH` environment variable before `/usr/bin`. When you install rvm, you should get instructions to put this:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"  # This loads RVM into a shell session.
```

somewhere into a file that is sourced when starting a shell, such as `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Generally, this should be done via `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"` in your shell's profile script, at the very end. For Bash, this is `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc` depending on how you've got things set up. If it's already in there, then something else is likely modifying the path AFTER the RVM script executes.

Comment: Thanks, I was still looking for this :)

Comment: Sure thing. Although, it seems that Kevin's shell has RVM loaded, so the RVM script must be working, which rules it down to a PATH modification after the fact, I would think.

Answer (score 1):

It would probably make sense to remove existing ruby packages in Ubuntu if you are using rvm, at least that's my understanding when I followed the instructions in http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
rvm use ruby-1.9.2-p290 
gem install rails
```

Don't use `sudo gem install` when you are using RVM.

Comment: Good catch, that might actually be the problem. Don't use sudo, and `chown -R you:you` your ~/.rvm directory as root if you did.

Answer (score 0):

**Thank you, prusswan!!***

I tried installing multi-user rvm on ubuntu 11.10 but it (okay, I) was confused and kept doing single-user installs.

Finally gave up and looked at your suggestion, which led me to Joshua Frye's railsready script, which worked like a charm without rvm.  I couldn't be happier.  Now I have to install a database and get going with Rails.

The script is [here](https://github.com/joshfng/railsready).  Works for OSX as well.